# Using aliased result of function in where clause

Tags: mysql

I want to pull specific rows from a table where the date matches a certain date. First I'm converting the date string to date format, here's the query:

```
SELECT id, str_to_date(candidate.AddDate,"%d/%m/%Y") n FROM candidate WHERE n='2016-01-01';
```

But I get the error "Unknown column 'n' in WHERE clause"

How do I make the query use the result of str_to_date in the where clause?

Comment: *"It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the `WHERE` clause is executed."* -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: You can, however, refer to column aliases in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses (because they are processed after the column values are computed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use the alias on the same level, because isnt created at that time

```
SELECT id, 
       Str_to_date(candidate.adddate, "%d/%m/%y") n 
FROM   candidate 
WHERE  Str_to_date(candidate.adddate, "%d/%m/%y") = '2016-01-01';
```

Or create a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT id, 
               Str_to_date(candidate.adddate, "%d/%m/%y") n 
        FROM   candidate 
     ) T
WHERE  n = '2016-01-01';
```

Comment: or HAVING - but a better idea is to store valid dates in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT id, adddate from candidate C where C.adddate = "2016-01-01"
```

Why cant you pull all the table rows where the given date is 2016-01-01. Is this what you want? Or something else. If you have stored the date as date field you dont really need to do str_to_time.

If it is stored as string then

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(candidate.adddate, '%d/%m/%Y') x FROM   candidate 
 ) C WHERE  x = '2016-01-01';
```

Comment: The actual code is going to be a lot more complex with between date comparisons etc.